# what can i do to update a column multiple times in same update query?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-update

I want to update a column multiple times in same update query. I have a table in ms SQL database I want to update a field than again update that field in the same update query. for example i have a column "col" in sample table what i want to do is to set "col" values to "x" than to "y" in same SQL statement.

```
what i can do to achieve this?
```

Comment: please show some sample data and expected result.Your explanation is not much clear

Comment: write a case statement in update query.

Comment: @XING UPDATE tutorials_tbl SET tutorial_id='bye',tutorial_id='bye_again'

Comment: Then why don't your directly update it to 'bye_again'. Whats the need to updating it twice in same query. Also are you running it 2 times,  
      UPDATE tutorials_tbl 
      SET tutorial_id= case when tutorial_id = 'Hello' then
                                 'bye'
                             when tutorial_id='bye' then                                                                 
                                 'bye_again'
                       end;

Comment: @XING yes i have tried UPDATE tutorials_tbl
    SET tutorial_id = CASE tutorial_id
        WHEN 'bye' THEN 'hello' 
       WHEN 'hello' THEN 'bye'
        ELSE tutorial_id
        
    END    but how i can wrap this up in same query.

Comment: Same query means,,,Thats whole is a single query only

Comment: @XING yes i want to do in single query

Comment: @Aleksej i have updated the post

Comment: If you update a field first to 'a' then to 'b', in the end it will contain 'b', and there will be no trace of the fact that you first updated it to 'a'; so, what is your need? please post some sample data and desired result

Comment: please add example and some reasonable reason... Are there any Triggers or anything writing changelog? Else it is as @Aleksej wrote, there is no trace...

Answer (score 0):

You CANNOT do it in one command.
ONE Statement updates ONE Row, as many fields/values as you give.

You CAN update in one statement as long as you add two commands:

```
UPDATE table SET value=1;UPDATE table SET value=2;
```

But i think, that is not what you want?